# Unidentified squash

Tags: squash

I have a rogue squash plant growing in my yard. It’s producing a yellow like squash, but is not shaped like a yellow squash, it’s shaped more like a delicata squash with light green on the very end. Its been producing quite a few squash also. It’s delicious, has a smooth nutty flavor but I just have no idea what it is. This isn’t the first time I’ve had rogue squash growing in my yard.[image]

Comment: Are you tossing kitchen seeds into your compost or directly into the garden? Purchased squash can well be F1 hybrids that produce Lord knows what in the next generation. Save **these seeds** for their nutty squash that should now come true to form.

Answer (score 1):

Looks superficially similar (overall shape and green tip) to "Candy Roaster" variety. Sometimes called "North Georgia Candy Roaster"